# Is it still possible to display a Google Map in an AIR app (as3)?

Tags: google-maps, actionscript-3

I know that Google depreciated the API for flash but do you know if there is another way to embbed a google map in an AIR app (As3) ?

I'd like to display this map in my app : https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1Y6r-uVjgWcHlbxWJFhva1bwzxpP2nFxa&ll=-21.786923558605633%2C167.14388498022396&z=7

Comment: Are you saying that using AIR's built-in browser (_StageWebView_) to load some `https://www.` link is not working? How about when using the `iFrame` embed code shown under options menu? It's not clear what else you've tried and how/why it's not working. There is also [static (image) maps](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/StaticMapService.GetMapImage?1m2&1i31198&2i17982&2e2&3u7&4m2&1u800&2u869&5m6&1e3&5sen&6sgb&10b1&12b1&14i1301875&client=google-maps-pro&token=20161) as next option too...

Comment: PS: For static images, just add your own custom icons that when clicked will use `URLStream` to load the html source code (`view-source:https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1Y6r-uVjgWcHlbxWJFhva1bwzxpP2nFxa&ll=-21.77672161478984%2C167.1438849802239&z=7`) for specific location and then you use String functions to parse data like `La cardinale nord`... Just some ideas I got within 1 minute of looking at your problem and using Chrome browser's Developer Tools. PPS: I did not down-vote you but try to think like a programmer (_eg:_ engineer / problem solver) and we will help you when stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'app' an actual mobile application, you could use a *better* webview ANE or Google Maps ANE for those kind of things.
You can find both here: https://tuarua.github.io/. I only tested webview ANE and it's fantastic!
If your 'app' is a swf embedded in html (I see no purpose of doing such a thing), then **maybe** you could overlay transparent swf over the html content with.